# How to load a html page with css in PHP

Tags: php, html

I wonderring that how to load a html page in PHP with all the css and bootstrap. I have used the "include(file.html)" but it just show the plain html without any css. Is there any way to also load the css that is linked in the html file ? Thanks

Comment: rename it to `.php` or instruct your server to treat those "as" php - question's a tad unclear though as to what contains what and how it's run.

Comment: You shouldn't ignore comments/answer or abandon/leave your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `<link>` tag as shown below in your HTML. The CSS will not be included until you send the your HTML to the browser, though. Otherwise, you will have to use the `<style></style>` tag in the header of your HTML (also, inline styles are a possibility). Note: The link tag assumes you have a directory named CSS in your webroot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">  <!-- Right here.-->
    </head>
    <body>
        The content of the document......
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS in the header might look like ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <style><!-- Right here.-->
            h1 {color:red;}
            p {color:blue;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        The content of the document......
    </body>
</html>
```

If you change the name of your file to `file.php`, you might be able to simple use `include/require styles.css` inside of `file.php` like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <?= include 'styles.css'; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        The content of the document......
    </body>
</html>
```

However, be sure your include_path is set appropriately. Additionally, doing this would mean putting the various selectors and rules within a `<style></style>` tag like in the previous example.